# Calling apply() on a function

Tags: javascript

I have the following code, so when calling `squareMem(10)`, what does `this` in `f.apply(this,arguments)` refers to?

```
function square(num){
    return num*num;
}

function memoize(f){
                var cache = {};

                return function(){

                    var key = JSON.stringify(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));

                    if(key in cache){
                        console.log('From cache...');
                        return cache[key];
                    }else{
                        console.log('Computing..');
                        return cache[key] = f.apply(this,arguments); // what does `this` refer to?
                    }

                }

            }

var squareMem = memoize(square);
squareMem(10);//100
```

Comment: `this` refers to the *current context*, always. When used with apply, it means that the `this` in *the called function's context* will be the value specified which currently refers to .. :) However, `this` (in all the code presented) will merely be `window`.

Comment: so in this case, this is the context of squareMem? and the `arguments` is 10?

Comment: and instead of using `f.apply(this,arguments)` can it simply be f(arguments)?

Comment: Arguments is an array-like object with `[10]`. Since squareMem (the anon function) wasn't called with a context itself, `this = window` in there, so window is also passed as the context to the apply.

Comment: No. .apply/.call [*require* the context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply). However, if you don't want to pass a *particular* context, `.apply(null, ..)`

Comment: how about not using `apply`, just call the function `f` directly and passing the argument to it? in this case the argument is 10.

Comment: In this case that will work (with the `square` function), but that won't be general across `memoizedFn(1,2,3,4)` - `arguments` is used for *variadic* functions.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51542/discussion-between-blake-and-user2864740)

Comment: @user2864740 `this` is not the context. If you call `f.apply(3,arguments);`, then `3` is hardly a context, wouldn't you agree?

Comment: @zeroflagL https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply - I don't agree. In this case the primitive number will be converted, such that `this -> new Number(3)`, which is entirely inline with how apply is defined to work.

Comment: @user2864740 Only if not in strict mode. But that wasn't the point.

Comment: @zeroflagL Feel free to write an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The `this` will refer to the context in which the memoized function is invoked.  It's only really useful if the original function uses `this`:

```
function square2(num) {
   return this + ": " + (num*num);
}

var o = { };
var d = new Date();
var f = memoize(square2);
o.f = memoize(square2);
d.f = memoize(square2);

f(20)   => "[object Window]: 400"
o.f(20) => "[object Object]: 400"
d.f(20) => "Sun Apr 27 2014 15:03:41 GMT-0500 (CDT): 400"
```

Answer (score 0):

every function executes within a context.
The first objects you define in a js app are in the global context (window) .
Inside a function, `this` refers to the calling context.
Your square function has no context : it depends only on its argument.
Some functions needs a context.
Most common example is console.log.
This function must have `console` as context.
If you write :

```
var logMe = console.log;
logMe('hello');
```

you'll get : `TypeError: Illegal invocation` .

Because the console.log function make use of `this` === `console`, and this context is lost when you only keep the function reference with logMe = console.log  ==> fail.

Note that the cost of the caching you're using is very given its implementation (JSONing the arguments), especially for `square()` an integer -> integer function, you'd much better make use of a simple array to cache the results, i'm not even sure a multiply is not faster than a scarce array memory access.  I guess some benchmark must be done to be sure the caching is not more expensive than the bare compute.